# Is a conversion from a double to a float always potentially invoking undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, floating-point, standards, undefined-behavior, c99

Here is the relevant part of the standard (6.3.1.5.2 Real floating types) of C99 :

> When a double is demoted to float, a long double is demoted to double or
> float, or a value being represented in greater precision and range than required by its
> semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly converted (including to its own type), if the value
> being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value
> being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be
> represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable
> value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is
> outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

In order to avoid undefined behavior, every time I want to convert a `double` to a `float`, I would have to manually check that the values of the double can be represented in the range of the float, correct ?

Comment: As long as the `double` is in the representable range of `float`, down-casting will not invoke UB. You don't have to explicitly check again if it's already a pre-condition.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree with your comment. My question was about the generic case without any knowledge of the value of the double.

Comment: On many systems, double and float have the same representation and then you can obviously convert away between them without any checks or UB. The standard text is written to cover all cases.

Comment: If the system uses IEEE-754 format, then the IEEE Standard provides definitions for what should be the result of overflow (`+/- inf`) or underflow (subnormal or zero) conversions. *I think.* But that's not *implicit* in the C99 Standard. *I think.*

Comment: If `float` supports infinity, no `double` is outside its range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ooh, I didn't think of +/- infinity, I'll look into it.

Comment: I'd expect if  `((fabs(some_double) <= HUGE_VALF))`, then conversion does not have UB.  If false, maybe UB.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

If you are converting `double` to `float`, and if you have no idea what the values might be, then for well-defined behavior you will want to check the range of each value first, and take appropriate action if a value is too large to fit in type `float`.

You'd want to do it this way even if the result in the overflow case weren't undefined, because whatever the overflow result was, it wouldn't necessarily be what you wanted.  (Depending on the application, you probably want to report an error back to your user/caller.)